# Ayuda ¿Cómo hacer que el programa muestre un mensaje diciendo que un elemento no existe?

Tags: java

Yo y mi amigo vamos empezando en esto de la programación y lo eh estado ayudando en un programa que le pidieron en la escuela el cual tenia que hacer que al seleccionar un elemento volviera al menú principal, otra opción para salir cuando lo quisiera el usuario, etc. Todo eso ya esta listo solo nos falto una opción la cual es que si un elemento no existe se muestre un mensaje diciéndolo pero ya nos volvimos locos intentándolo pero no nos queda como debería.

Les dejo todo el código del programa para ver si nos pueden ayudar, gracias.

```
package Familia8A;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Familia8A {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int c=0; 
    int r=0;
    int res=0; 
    String nom="";
    boolean bandera=false;

String[][] gases = {{"Helio","He","2","4.0","0","no tiene"},
                    {"Neon","Ne","10","20.1","0","no tiene"},
                    {"Argon","Ar","18","39.9","0","no tiene"},
                    {"Cripton","Kr","36","83.8","0,2","no tiene"},
                    {"Xenon","Xe","54","131.2","0,2,4,6,8","2.6"},
                    {"Radon","Rn","86","222","0,2","no tiene"},
                    {"Oganeson","Og","118","294","0","no tiene"}
};
do{
    bandera=false;
      nom=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"\n Ingresa el nombre del elemento que deseas conocer: \nHelio\nNeon\nArgon\nCripton\nXenon\nRadon\nOganeson\nPresiona 1 para Salir","Gases Nobles",3);
      for(r = 0; r <=6; r = r + 1){
          if(nom.equalsIgnoreCase(gases[r][0]))
          {
     res= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1.Simbolo\n2.Numero atomico\n3.Peso atomico\n4.Todo"));
            bandera=true;
            switch(res)
             {
                 case 1:
                 {


                     {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Simbolo : "+gases[r][1] );
                         break;
                     }
                 }
                     case 2:
                 {

                     {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No.Atomico : "+gases[r][2] );
                         break;
                     }
                 }
                     case 3:
                 {

                     {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Peso Atomico : "+gases[r][3] );
                         break;
                     }
                 }
                     case 4:
                 {


                     {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Nombre: "+gases[r][0]+"\n"+"Simbolo: 
                         "+gases[r][1]+"\n"+"No.Atomico: "+gases[r][2]+"\n"+"Peso Atomico: "+gases[r] 
                     [3]+"\n"+"No.Oxidacion: "+gases[r][4]+"\n"+"Electronegatividad: "+gases[r][5]);
                         break;
                     }
                 }
                     default:{
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No existe esa Opcion");
                     }
                 }//switch

                     }//if
              }//for
              if(bandera==false){
                c=Integer.parseInt(nom);
              }
            }while(c!=1);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adentro del `if(bandera==false){ }` debes de escribir el `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No existe esa Opcion");` ya que la bandera indica si el elemento fue encontrado o no, espero que los ayude.